# Desktop and Taskbar crashing/refreshing when signed into Microsoft account

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, taskbar, desktop

**TL;DR:** explorer.exe crashes when a user profile is logged into a Microsoft account. This does not happen on local accounts, even local accounts made on the same machine.

---

This is about the fourth time I've run into this across several difference devices within the last two weeks, all signed into different Microsoft accounts. The one thing linking them all together is that the owner is signed into a Microsoft account. Local users do not have this issue until they sign into said account, then the problem resurfaces (even across fresh Windows 10 installs). I'm surprised I haven't seen anything about it as of yet. Most of the machines are on 1903 (one was on 1809 originally), though the error continues even once updated to 1909. This problem also continues even when booted into safe mode.

**What's going on**

- Immediately after login, the desktop and taskbar constantly crashes/refreshes every few seconds.
- You cannot open the start menu, settings page, file explorer, launch anything either via icons or WIN + R.
- To launch anything, you have to access the Task Manager through CTRL + ALT + DEL and run a new task. However, every time explorer crashes you get tabbed out of the box

Looking up the symptoms, many threads suggest disabling Windows Error Reporting Service, which has only fixed the issue once, and only temporarily. Others say it is Norton or other similar anti-viruses, but none of these machines have Norton. Two had ESET Node32, but even when that was removed the crashing continued.

**Other suggestions I've tried:**
*(restarting the machine after each)*

- removing Adobe Reader and putting all PDF files on the desktop into a
  folder (which again only worked once and only temporarily). [suggestion from here](https://superuser.com/questions/1253687/windows-10-desktop-screen-and-taskbar-keep-refreshing-tried-many-ways-but-stil)
- completely removing every icon and file off the desktop
- removing iCloud (only one of the machines had that, but still did not fix it)
- removing IDT-Audio drivers (none of them had that, but I removed/uninstalled realtek ones as well to be safe.)
- downgrading/upgrading/removing display drivers, like Nvidia, etc. (Nothing changed there either)
- running `sfc /scannow` (did not find any violations)
- running `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth`,  `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`, and `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Checkhealth`(ran successfully, but did not fix the problem)
- in-place Windows upgrade via thumbdrive
- uninstalling Feedback Hub, disabling Timeline, setting Diagnostic data from full to basic and a few others following [this
  guide/fix](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/windows-taskbar-icons-randomly-and-periodically-blink.3324292/post-20313550) that worked for someone else, similar to [this one](https://borncity.com/win/2018/05/14/windows-10-v1803-fix-for-explorer-timeline-crashes/) and the first comment [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsinsiders/comments/8gd2zt/windows_explorer_constantly_crashing/) as well.
- disabling any and all Microsoft account settings/themes syncing, but it might be a bit late for that to go into effect?

With one of the machines that I disabled the Windows Error Reporting on, the crashing stops but then I get an alert saying the following:

```
explorer.exe - System Error

The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application
```

I can hit `OK`, but that just causes explorer.exe to crash again and the alert reappears.

.dmp logs on at least one machine say the "Fault Module Name :" was `SHELL32.dll` with an exception code of `0xc0000409` [through AppCrashView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) and a subcode of `Subcode: 0x7 FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT` with [WinDbg Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86)

**full .dmps are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LJpDZvavoOIQYY5F1iorRgAK3C6uukL7?usp=sharing)**

Are there any ideas on what this could be? Or how to fix and/or prevent it? (other than just telling people to *not* sign into a Microsoft account).

Thanks!

Comment: Corrupted profile., don't know how to solve it, would consult M$ Support.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the syncing settings for the profile linked to the MS account.

Comment: You can contact Microsoft Customer Support at +1 800-642-7676 or http://microsoft.com/contactus. You can now also give or take Tech Support remotely using Quick Assist in Windows 10 https://www.thewindowsclub.com/quick-assist-windows-10

Comment: Look at my post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1492576/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-10-file-explorer/1492598#1492598).  Same problem.. I too have felt your pain.  BTW, I even broke into the debugger with full symbols loaded and STILL couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Just an FYI, it's more efficient to simply run `/restorehealth` with `DISM` and to skip `/checkhealth` or `/scanhealth`, unless the PC doesn't have an internet connection, (required for `/restorehealth`, but not sure about the other two).  Also, `DISM` should be run before `SFC` since the latter depends on the data the former is verifying.

Comment: @JW0914 good to know, I was just following several guides. I can't remember if I actually did them in the order posted, but I did do them. Thank you tho! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a fix for you.  Your crash is different than the one I was getting (lucky for you).  I pulled down your .dmp files and opened them in a debugger.

It looks like you are crashing in:
`shell32.dll!Microsoft::Windows::FileExplorer::Banners::BannerData::GetFolderScope()`

1. Open `regedit`.
2. Go to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\`
3. Look for sub-keys called `BannerSettings` or `BannerStore` (each may have subkeys).
4. Back them up (although it won't matter, it makes people feel better).
5. Delete `BannerSettings` and `BannerStore`, including anything under them (or just one if you have only one).
6. Reboot.
7. Jump for joy (or curse my name).

I am betting it will work.

Comment: Ahhh! That worked! Apparently I just wasn't using the debugger correctly. . .  However, this one's crashes were slightly different than the others, as this was the only one who got the overrun buffer when error reporting was disabled. The other 3, explorer.exe would just continue crashing even when disabled. It looked like those reg files I deleted was for OneDrive, so I'm guessing that OneDrive syncing their settings to the cloud somehow corrupted them, as it seems like it's okay now. I'll have to check the DMP files on the others and try this fix again.

Comment: Still weird how so many machines made by different manufacturers, let alone build factors/types (laptop versus tower, brand name versus custom build) and/or Windows versions (home, pro, 1809, 1903, 1909) have come up with this issue seemingly all at once. . . If I may ask, what was the crash that you were getting?

Comment: If it worked @Raeanne_Moriarty, please select this the correct answer.  I was getting a crash having to do with the disk drive controller.